# Ionic side bar menu not working on multi pages

Tags: angularjs, menu, ionic-framework, sidebar

I have an issue with side menu in ionic , 
- I have Multi pages 
- I convert app from tab to menu 
- menu appear in first page loaded by swipping .
- when I click on toggle button get this error

### *Cannot call method 'toggleLeft' of undefined*

in the controller I put this function

```js
 .controller('ServicesController', ['$scope', function ($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

    $scope.Openmenu = function() {
      $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
    };
   }
```

and Button ionic code

```html
 <button  ng-click="Openmenu()"  class="button button-clear button-icon icon ion-navicon-round " ></button>
```

is there any thing missing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `menu-toggle` directive:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/menuToggle/

You could try to update your button to use that instead:

```
<button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-clear button-icon icon ion-navicon-round"></button>
```